# i cant access lots of websites for some reason, it just says connection reset

Tags: windows-7

A while ago my computer started playing up and then I couldn't access sites like adf.ly, google.com and facebook.com to name a few. I tried restarting my modem a few times however it still doesn't work. I also booted up in safe mode and that didn't work so I'm not sure where I go from here to fix this problem.

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium and it's new as this is on my new laptop that I got a few months ago for my birthday.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus?

Comment: no i dont, is that why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its likely you got a virus of some sort that played around with your hosts file.

Find Notepad (Start Menu -> Programs -> Accessories -> Notepad), when you see notepad, right-click it and click `Run as Administrator`. When it opens, click `File` then `Open` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) and where the file name bar is enter `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and hit enter or the `Open` button.

Remove any lines except one like this, or remove everything and copy & paste this line in:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

Comment: k i jsut opened my hosts file and there is a heaps of lines of numbers then urls with google and facebook there, do i remove them?

Comment: Yes, remove them all except the one in my question, or remove them all and paste in `127.0.0.1    localhost`